# Max of a list of strings in Java

Tags: java

I have data in the form of

```
String[] values = {"4,8", "1,6", "7,8", "1,5"}
```

where I have to find the max of the second element and if there are more than two of the max ("4,8" and "7,8"), find the one with the min of the first. So the output of values should be a string "4,8"

I am new to JAVA and I am not sure how exactly to go about this. I tried to use string split and something like

```
        int[] num = new int[values.length];
        int[] num2 = new int[values.length];

        for (int i = 0; i<values.length; i++){
            String[] test = values[i].split(",");
            int nummed = Integer.parseInt(test[0]);
            int nummed2 = Integer.parseInt(test[1]);
            num[i] = nummed;
            num2[i] = nummed2;

            //System.out.println(test[0]);
            //System.out.println(test[1]);
        }
```

but it is quickly becoming very complicated and I would need to know the index or maybe filter out data to find the min of the first item.

Comment: It's hard to understand your reasoning for your output. Is there any way you could describe it more clearly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be enough

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] values = {"4,8", "1,6", "7,8", "1,5"}; // try {"4,8", "1,6", "7,8", "1,5", "1,9"}
        int right = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int left = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i<values.length; i++){
            String[] test = values[i].split(",");
            int nummed = Integer.parseInt(test[0]);
            int nummed2 = Integer.parseInt(test[1]);
            if (nummed2 >= right) {
                if (right != nummed2) {
                    left = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                }
                right = nummed2;
                if (nummed < left) {
                    left = nummed;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(left + "," + right);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class StringManipulation {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(output());
  }

  private static String output() {
    String[] values = {"4,8", "1,6", "7,8", "1,5"};
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int first = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      String[] arr = values[i].split(",");
      if(Integer.parseInt(arr[1]) >= max){
        max = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
        first = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]) < first ? Integer.parseInt(arr[0]):first;
      }
    }
    return (first) + "," + (max);
  }
}
```

There could be multiple approaches to this problem. Given my understanding of the question, this is one of the simplest solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing with your solution, Tested. Works as expected, It was hard to type it all on mobile though.

```
public static void main(String arg[])
{

String[] values = {"4,8", "1,6", "7,8", "1,5","2,8"};
  int[] num = new int[values.length];
        int[] num2 = new int[values.length];

        for (int i = 0; i<values.length; i++){
            String[] test = values[i].split(",");
            int nummed = Integer.parseInt(test[0]);
            int nummed2 = Integer.parseInt(test[1]);
            num[i] = nummed;
            num2[i] = nummed2;

            //System.out.println(test[0]);
            //System.out.println(test[1]);
        }

    int max=0;
    int min=0;
    for(int i=0;i<num2.length;i++)
    {
     if(num2[i]>max) {
       max =num2[i];
       min=num[i];
     }
      else if(num2[i]==max)
        min = min>=num[i]?num[i]:min;
    }
   System.out.println(min+","+max);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that makes use of the fluent `Comparator` api, stream api and `BigDecimal`s:

```java
        String[] values = {"4,8", "1,6", "7,8", "1,5"};

        // create a custom comparator
        Comparator<BigDecimal> comparator = Comparator
                // first, comparing only the right side - the remainders
                .comparing((BigDecimal num) -> num.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE))
                // then, comparing the left side - the decimal part
                .thenComparing(num -> num.setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN));

        // find the max value using java stream api
        Arrays.stream(values)
                // replace commas with dots
                .map(num -> num.replace(',', '.'))
                // map values to bigdecimal
                .map(BigDecimal::new)
                // find the max element by our custom comparator
                .max(comparator)
                // print if an element is found (if the array was not empty)
                .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```